# I am using python matplotlib.backend to create a graph I want to show date time at an angle how do you do this?

Tags: python

Hi I would like to display the x axis at an angle 
here is some of my code

```
    axis.grid(True)
    xs = range(numSamples)
    xs = times
    axis.plot(xs, ys)
```

Comment: The `x` axis, or the labels at the `x`-axis?

Comment: the labels at the x-axis